# Why do I get these file permissions?

Tags: linux, assembly, permissions, x86-64, system-calls

I wrote an assembly code to create a directory and a file in it, and they're created but with weird permissions - the directory is `drwxrwxrwx` and the file is `-r-xr-xr-x`.

As far as I tried, changing the `mode` argument can change the file permissions to 777, but I don't find a pattern in how I change it and the results. (It's 777 or 555).

`umask` is set to `0002`.

Why do I get full permissions for the directory? and what causes these permissions for the file? And how do I change the permissions?

I use these two lines to compile and link:

```
nasm run.s -f elf64 -o run.o
ld run.o -o run
```

I use Ubuntu over VMWare.

Code:

```
section    .data

dir_name:          db      'mynewdir', 0
dir_mode           equ     0

file_name:         db      'mynewfile', 0
file_mode          equ     0

section    .text

global     _start

_start:
    mov rdi, dir_name
    mov rsi, dir_mode
    mov rax, 83                ; sys_mkdir
    syscall

    mov rdi, dir_name
    mov rax, 80                ; sys_chdir
    syscall

    mov rdi, file_name
    mov rsi, file_mode
    mov rax, 85                ; sys_creat
    syscall

    mov rdi, 0
    mov rax, 60        ; sys_exit
    syscall
```

Strace:

```
$ strace ./run
execve("./run", ["./run"], [/* 63 vars */]) = 0
mkdir("mynewdir", 0)                    = 0
chdir("mynewdir")                       = 0
creat("mynewfile", 0)                   = 3
exit(0)                                 = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Comment: This looks correct. What assembler is this?

Comment: On my system, this seems to work as intended, except that `mynewdir` is created with permissions 0000 so `chdir` fails (do error checking!). Is this really the program you tested?

Comment: @fuz Thanks, I added this info to the question. And on mine it doesn't. I just re-executed it and it does the same.

Comment: Can you post the output of "strace run" for me?

Comment: Normally you'd pass octal `0777` for permissions, to let umask mask off bits.  What Linux kernel version are you using?  Maybe the handling of `mode=0` changed between your version and fuz's kernel version?  Definitely post `strace` output.

Comment: @fuz I posted strace

Comment: @PeterCordes It doesn't depend on what I set as mode. The permissions don't change.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @MichaelPetch 16.04.4

Comment: @Neo: Even if you pass `0444` or something to mkdir and creat?  Is there anything special about the parent directory, like sticky bit or setgid?  What filesystem are you using?  Is it FAT32 or something that doesn't support full Unix permissions?

Comment: Maybe an NFS mount? Or onto USB media?

Comment: @MichaelPetch It's in a shared directory with the host. Does that matter?

Comment: @MichaelPetch It's not a hosting provider, it's my Win8 laptop.

Comment: Try running your software from a  directory in Ubuntu that isn't shared.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I just tried, and permissions have changed! But I inserted 455 (`file_mode equ 455`) which is decimal for 707 octal to both, and got `-rwx---r-x` for file and `drwx---r-x` for dir (same permissions, but where did they come from?)

Comment: @MichaelPetch I use VMWare and there's an option for shared directory. I printed etc/fstab but my directory isn't there.

Comment: VMWare has some documentation, and rules for permissions (including for Linux guest and Windows hosts) at the bottom of this article: http://pubs.vmware.com/ws65_ace25/ws_user/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=ws_user&file=transferfiles.10.10.html

Comment: @Neo Looks like your program is working correctly. Try passing a mode like `0o777` to `mkdir` that actually makes sense. Make sure to delete the directory before the next run so it is actually recreated.

Comment: @MichaelPetch That was it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Adding the answer for future users:
Apparently, the reason for the unexpected results were the fact that the program was run in a shared-with-host directory with special permissions settings (VMWare defaults).
When I run this in a regular directory I get the results I expect, considering umask.